# Untar directory from large tarball

Tags: directory, tar, wildcards

How do I untar a directory that I don't know the path to? I only know the directory name.

I know how to untar a single file with a wildcard: `tar -xf somefile.tar.gz --wildcards --no-anchored 'index.php'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just take two passes at it:

```
$ tar -tf somefile.tar.gz | grep dir-i-am-looking-for | head -1
./foo/bar/dir-i-am-looking-for/somefile/bla/bla/bla
$ tar -xf somefile.tar.gz ./foo/bar/dir-i-am-looking-for
```

I don't see a "wildcard include" option in GNU tar.

Comment: In this case I'd omit the `| head -1`. Since he even doesen't know the correct path it could be that there are multiple directories with that name within the archive, so give him the chance to verify this.

Comment: Yes. I included it more as a thing to think about, not a requirement. A useful alternative would be `| dirname | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

Content of **script.pl**:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Archive::Tar;

## Check input arguments.
die qq[perl $0 <tar-file> <directory>\n] unless @ARGV == 2;

my $found_dir;

## Create a Tar object.
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new( shift );

## Get directory to search in the Tar object.
my $dir = quotemeta shift;

for ( $tar->get_files ) { 

    ## Set flag and extract when last entry of the path is a directory with same 
    ## name given as argument
    if ( ! $found_dir &&  $_->is_dir && $_->full_path =~ m|(?i:$dir)/\Z|o ) { 
        $found_dir = 1;
        $tar->extract( $_ );
        next;
    }   

    ## When set flag (directory already found previously), extract all files after
    ## it in the path.
    if ( $found_dir && $_->full_path =~ m|/(?i:$dir)/.*|o ) { 
        $tar->extract( $_ );
    }   
}
```

It accepts two arguments, first one the TAR file and second one the directory to extract. Run it like:

```
perl script.pl test.tar winbuild
```